# How to make a payment Intent to charge a connected account in Stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I would like to create a Stripe PaymentIntent with a direct charge to a connected account

Here is what I wrote

```
stripe.paymentIntents.create(
  {
    amount: 2000,
    currency: 'gbp',
    payment_method: 'pm_xxxx',
  }, {
    stripe_account: 'acct_1F2xxxxxxxxxx'
  },
  function(err, paymentIntent) {
    // asynchronously called
    // do something here
  }
);
```

What am I doing wrong??

The following code (without the connected account) works fine

```
stripe.paymentIntents.create(
  {
    amount: 2000,
    currency: 'gbp',
    payment_method: 'pm_xxxx',
  },
  function(err, paymentIntent) {
    // asynchronously called
    // do something here
  }
);
```

I suspect that is culprit because the console error says something about PaymentMethod....

**EDIT**: The code is correct and I found out that the issue is with Stripe because they requires some sort of further authentication. From Stripe documentation

> If you opt for direct charges, you will need to make sure that the
>   connected account is onboarded on the payment method you intend to
>   use. Direct charges require creating PaymentMethods on connected
>   accounts....
>
> If you’re creating PaymentMethods from the server, you
>   can make use of authentication using the Stripe-Account header with
>   any of our supported libraries.

I will work on it and see how to do it

Comment: This code is correct. If you get an error, it could be that you don't have access to the account that you passed in `stripe_account`. It's a bit tricky to help without knowing the exact error here. Also protip, you might want to talk to Stripe's support team directly since it's your third question in a row about PaymentIntents.

Comment: this is the error @koopajah `Error: No such payment_method: pm_1FdmPxxxxxxxxx; OAuth key or Stripe-Account header was used but API request was provided with a platform-owned payment method ID. Please ensure that the provided payment method matches the specified account.`

Comment: You give no indication you are doing anything wrong.

Comment: The code is correct. The problem is with Stripe - I have made an edit2 comment

Comment: the problem is that the PaymentMethod is created on the platform and then you try to use it on the connected account. That can never work. You need to look at this doc: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#creating-paymentmethods-directly-on-the-connected-account

Comment: You are right @koopajah. I have then decided to clone my payment intent in the server as per your guide. The cloned payment method works fine and I am able to create a payment intent on behalf of my connected account. The problem is now when I need to confirm/authenticate IN THE CLIENT. I am using flutter and the stripe_payment plugin and there is no way to authenticate

Comment: I don't know how the plugin works unfortunately. But client-side, when you initialize Stripe.js you need to explicitly set the connected account id too like this: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#creating-paymentmethods-directly-on-the-connected-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this https://medium.com/flutter-community/build-a-marketplace-in-your-flutter-app-and-accept-payments-using-stripe-and-firebase-72f3f7228625   which describes how to charge a connected account.

Basically you need to clone your payment methods in the server and then create your payment intent

Stripe docs for cloning payment methods: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/cloning-saved-payment-methods

Comment: How did you clone the payment method? The link is broken

Comment: Link Updated. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

With current version of Stripe SDK:

```
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
const stripe = require('stripe')('YOUR_KEY');

const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: 1000,
  currency: 'usd',
  automatic_payment_methods: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  transfer_data: {
    amount: 877,
    destination: '{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
  },
});
```

reference : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges?locale=en-GB